# Troubleshooting SPARQL rCurl queries in R

Tags: r, sparql, rcurl

I'm doing a sparql query against an authenticated endpoint in R using the SPARQL library.
The same query/endpoint/user works using the rrdf package.  Unfortuantely, once I get the query working, I need to process the data in R and update the graph with the answers, which rrdf can't do.

Setting up a few variables first, the below query works using rrdf:
`sparql.remote(myEndpoint,myQuery,'rowvar',myUsername,myUserpwd)`

Using SPARQL, this does not work:
`SPARQL(myEndpoint,myQuery,curl_args=c('username'=myUsername,'userpwd'=myUserpwd))`

The error is `Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: ''` which I think means no document is coming back.

So, any tips on how to debug the curl call underneath all this?

Comment: "So, any tips on how to debug the curl call underneath all this?" That's really too broad for Stack Overflow.  That said, rather than just assuming that "no document is coming back.", it would make sense to see how SPARQL is using the curl args, then try running the same curl query, and actually looking at what results you're getting.

Comment: I don't mean this offensively, but that's really the sort of thing you should do *before* you post a question to Stack Overflow.  For instance, see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1281433).  The more debugging efforts and results that you can show in your question (e.g., what is curl actually returning, not what you assume it's returning), the better the question, and the better the types of responses that you'll get.

Comment: Identifying how to do that was nontrivial, I am not a web developer.  It took some time to determine that curl arguments were the reason and not some non-standard assumptions involving the endpoint.  Also, the curl verbose flag was something that I didn't even know existed until I went and asked an actual web developer how to debug this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And the solution in this case was that the username parameter is not used in curl.
The correct call is:
`SPARQL(myEndpoint,myQuery,curl_args=c('userpwd'=paste(myUsername,':',myUserpwd,sep='')))`

Actually debugging it was done via calls to getURL from RCurl against the basic endpoint until I got something that worked.
`getURL(url=endpoint,userpwd="testusername:testpassword",verbose=TRUE)`

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Not possible for 48 hours for noobs.  A limitation of stack exchange.