# How to give logindata to SPARQL R function to update virtuoso endpoint?

Tags: r, sparql, virtuoso

I want to use R package SPARQL to run set of INSERT queries to a Virtuoso endpoint.
How to give username and password to the function and which url to be used?
When I tried

```
tmpRes=SPARQL('myserver:8890/sparql',update=updateQry)
```

I got error: Error: SPARQL Request Failed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Troubleshooting SPARQL rCurl queries in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24401227/troubleshooting-sparql-rcurl-queries-in-r)

Comment: Thanks! 
I used this code ```tmpRes=SPARQL(endpoint,update=uqry,curl_args=c('userpwd'=paste0(myusername,':',myuserpwd)))``` Currently I'm getting the error and extra Warning:
Error: SPARQL Request Failed
In addition: Warning message:
In testCurlOptionsInFormParameters(.params) :
  Found possible curl options in form parameters: userpwd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

`tmpRes=SPARQL('http://dba:dba@myserver:8890/sparql', query=updateQry)`

note both changes.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The following document on [Analyzing Linked Open Data with R](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VOSLODStatsAnalysisR) shows how to query a Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint from R.